# How do I use a models id while making a factory of the same model?

Tags: laravel, factory

What I'm trying to do is get the user id in a factory so I can store a hashed version of it:

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'hashed_id' => Hashids::encode($this->id),
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

`$this->id` in `'hashed_id' => Hashids::encode($this->id)` is suppose to refer to the `User::class`

**Error**

> ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::$id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make an observer to follow every database record creation.

That will allow you to proxy the creation and modify the data.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers

Or you can directly add a hook to the model events on the model.

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($user) {
        $user->hashed_id = Hashids::encode($user->id);
    });
}
```

Comment: This gave me the idea to use model events instead. You can change your answer to include this code: https://www.codepile.net/raw/dJKMRjBp.php and I'll give it to you. Thank you

Comment: Observers simply wrappers to the model events. I you should use `created` instead of creating.

Comment: I tried to use created, but it did not work since the hashed_id can't be null.

Comment: So the creating was able to give you the id? That I didn’t know.

Comment: Yup! I didn't know ether until I tried. I didn't think it would work.

Comment: Ahhhh, okay. So you were right after all. For some unknown reason my tests were green but there wasn't anything saving to the db. You can't get an id before a record has been created in the db. I had to use created and turn my hash_id to nullable.

Comment: Thats the one makes sense. You shouldn’t have id until you “created” a model.